# Preferred way to add external jars as separate files or as User defined library in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

Hi in the days of complex build tools for dependencies management as maven and Gradle in our project still add external dependencies in the SVN and then add them to the buildpath as well as the eclipse project with its **.classpath** and **.project**. So I am wondering what is the preferred way to do that.

1. Add jars one by one

[image]

or

2. Define custom user library and put all the dependencies there

[image]

Is there such thing as good or bad way and from what they depend?

Answer (score 1):

2nd way it's always reusable in any project in the same workspace. So if we are going to add a certain stack of external libs to several projects, rather to do it in a methodical way. *User Libs* is a good aproach. In my opinion.

However any change in the composition of the *User Lib* will impact all the projects that use it.